# Get position of a unsupported character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have characters like this:

[image: special characters]

In a SQL Server database with a `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation; not sure which one of them are unsupported, but they don't appear in SQL Server Management Studio; the only way to see those characters are

```
declare @campo_mbore varchar(500)

select @campo_mbore = campo_rompebolas 
from tabla 
where id = X

print @campo_mbore
```

Is there a regular expression to find and replace with '' the unsupported characters? I have to show every other character supported in Latin1, but I need to get rid of those characters. Editing the rows is not a solution.

Comment: If there were "unsupported" (by collation) characters you'd see "?" instead of them. Do you mean unprintable characters? Or what? The fact is that SSMS can show or not show them in different modes (try also "results to text" mode) but this is client visualisation problem only

Comment: @sepupic I came across this https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/removing-null-characters-0x00-from-values-in-sql-server/ I think this is the answer, I did a replace and I can see those strange characters